# Kinect Skeleton Scaling and Positioning

Tags: c#, xna, kinect

Using color and depth stream I've obtained an Image of me and I have managed to scale and change the positioning of it. However, I couldn't do the same thing to Skeleton data. What I want to do is scale and position the skeleton onto my image so that I can place my Gus mask on my head and volleyball to my hand in proper sizes. How can I do the same thing to the skeleton?

This is the line where I scaled and positioned the image:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(activeSkeletons[p.Key].image, position1, activeSkeletons[p.Key].image.Bounds, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```

Drawing function:

```
private void DrawSkeleton(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Vector2 resolution, Texture2D img)
{

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Player> p in activeSkeletons)
    {
        if (activeSkeletons[p.Key].image != null)
        {
            if (p.Key == indexes[0])
            {
                //Drawing the image - first player
                spriteBatch.Draw(activeSkeletons[p.Key].image, position1, activeSkeletons[p.Key].image.Bounds, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
            }
            else {
                //Drawing the image - second player
                spriteBatch.Draw(activeSkeletons[p.Key].image, position2, activeSkeletons[p.Key].image.Bounds, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
            }
        }

        foreach (Joint joint in p.Value.skeleton.Joints)
        {
            if (joint.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
            {
                //Drawing the skeleton
                var colorPoint = kinect.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToColorPoint(joint.Position, kinect.ColorStream.Format);
                spriteBatch.Draw(img, new Rectangle(Convert.ToInt32(colorPoint.X), Convert.ToInt32(colorPoint.Y), 10, 10), Color.White);
                if (joint.JointType == JointType.HandRight && joint.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
                {
                    //Volleyball
                    dopKonum = new Vector2(colorPoint.X - dop.Width / 2, colorPoint.Y - dop.Height / 2);
                    spriteBatch.Draw(dop, dopKonum, Color.White);
                }
                else if (joint.JointType == JointType.Head && joint.TrackingState != JointTrackingState.NotTracked)
                {
                    //Gus Fring
                    gusKonum = new Vector2(colorPoint.X - gus.Width / 2, colorPoint.Y - gus.Height / 2);
                    spriteBatch.Draw(gus, gusKonum, Color.White);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how it looks:

[image: Kinect]

Hope I explained it well.

Comment: maybe show us the whole code? (atleast the part that handles all drawing and getting position data)

Comment: I've added the function http://txtup.net/kNKJN can you please check it?

Comment: I read the question a few times, and I'm still not sure what you're asking for... the head and volleyball seem to be positioned properly, is it the scale of these sprites that you'd like to change or the sprites of your skeleton markers?

Comment: I meant positioning that mask, volleyball and pink joint points over the bottom-left human picture. (also scale them suitably)